# Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin Forms not deploy

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms app with Visual Studio 2015 running in Windows 10 hosted in VMWare Fusion 8.1.1 on a MacBookPro.
I connected a Moto G device to the Windows 10 machine (I can access to device with adb).
When I compile the project and try to deploy to the device the process never end. After build success message, VS 2015 go to Ready state and nothing happen.

What I can check? What is wrong?
Thank you!
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

Click build on the tab menu and then select configuration manager. In the opening window, you should click deploy option for your platform